# Why are there parentheses and dots after an array's name instead of brackets?

Tags: delphi, syntax

When accessing an element in an array the square brackets are used like so:

```
{'X is an int and Numbers is an int array'}
X := Numbers[8];
```

However, While reading others' code I sometimes find the following syntax:

```
{'PBox , SBox1 , SBox2 are arrays of int , And X,Y are ints'}
Result := Result or PBox(.SBox1[X] or SBox2[Y].);
```

1. What does it mean to have parentheses after the array's name, as in `PBox(someNumber)`? Is this another way to access an array element?
2. What does the "." before SBox1 and after SBox2 mean? Both SBox1 and SBox2 are arrays. The code compiles without error but I don't know what those dots are for.

Comment: It took me almost a minute to see what is going on here! The `(.` way of writing `[` is very uncommon! And it is also very uncommon to use a bitwise `or` to compute an index of an array! As a "noob", you **really** should begin with studying far simpler things than this! In addition, `PBox` is a very bad name of an integer array, since the `P` prefix usually denotes pointer types, such as `PInteger` (`=^Integer`).

Comment: @Andreas: Have you seen it before? I work with Delphi since '98 and never saw an array indexed with `(.`. The bitwise part I never saw too, but if the code use some API the bitwise `OR` would be need to set flags.

Comment: @Fabrico: I have never seen `(.` in an actual piece of code, but I knew about it (although, at first, I mistook it for `(*`, the alternative way of writing `{`). Bitwise `or` is something every programmer knows about. As you say, it is perhaps most often used to combine flags in "bitmaps", but there are far more applications than that if you work with low-level stuff. I have never seen a bitwise `or` as an array index, though...

Comment: @Andreas : I saw this in an implementation of the DES algorithm , pbox stands for permutation box.

Comment: The bitwise `OR` is quite common on Win API programming (it's common on some low level methods of VCL) - but indexing an array on a bitwise expression is something you don't see every day... ;-)

Comment: I prefer to use // comments as they don't confuse the C++ programmers as much. Also you don't need to put quote marks around your comments.

Comment: The (. and .) for [ and ] is a leftover from the early Turbo Pascal days, before all keyboards had the [] keys, IIRC. I haven't seen it for decades (dating myself here <g>). Same for the (* for { and *) for }.

Comment: @Ken White: That is how I understand it, too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, now I see what you do.

In fact, `(.` and `.)` are merely alternative ways (but very uncommon!) of writing `[` and `]` in Delphi.

If `PBox` is an array, then `PBox[a]` (or, equivalently, `PBox(.a.)`) would require `a` to be an integer, right? And if `SBox1[x]` and `SBox2[Y]` are integers, so is the bitwise `or` of them. (Bitwise `or` is an operation that takes two integers and returns a new integer.) Hence, `PBox(.SBox1[X] or SBox2[Y].)` is the `(SBox1[X] or SBox2[Y])`th element in the array `PBox`, that is, an integer. So it makes sense to compute the bitwise `or` between `Result` and this integer, which is what is done:

```
Result := Result or PBox(.SBox1[X] or SBox2[Y].);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andreas .. Now I get it:)

Comment: Now the `WeirdLookingArray: array(.1..10.) of string;` from the [The Future of the Delphi Compiler](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39174) finally makes sense!