# What does "(.1..10.)" mean in an array declaration?

Tags: delphi, syntax, pascal

Nick Hodges mentioned in [an article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39174) that the following still compiles:

```
var
  WeirdLookingArray: array(.1..10.) of string;
```

What is the meaning of "." in beginning and end?

Comment: just a guess, didnt read the article, but could it be psuedo code?

Comment: @TrevorMA: My answer below was too long to read?

Comment: @Andreas You wrote it after I posted that. Sorry.  Good to know though.  Does that work with all languages?

Comment: @TrevorMA: Only Delphi, I think.

Comment: @TrevorMA, yes, that article written as advertisment and not really worth reading. Check out first link in my answer for use in the other languages (C trigraphs, actually)

Comment: See also [Why are there parentheses and dots after an array's name instead of brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157123/why-are-there-parentheses-and-dots-after-an-arrays-name-instead-of-brackets)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(.` and `.)` are alternative ways of writing `[` and `]`, respectively.

You can also write `(*` and `*)` instead of `{` and `}`.

Comment: If I recollect correctly, the alternative syntax has something to do with certain older codepages having other characters in places of `[` and `]` (typically some accented letters). That is, it's not an issue now, but the syntax has been inherited from Pascal.

Comment: @Andriy: IIRC the problem was actually with certain European *keyboards* not having the appropriate keys for those symbols back in the day.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: Makes sense. But the two facts might be interconnected.

Comment: IIRC the CDC-6400 where Pascal (the first compiler?) was developed on/for  could pack 10 6-bit chars into a 60-bit word. It was more word than byte oriented. THat is also why there is supported for "packed" arrays. E.g. a packed array of char was an array of word, in which chars were packed, a non packed array had one char per word. Anyway, a lot of the 64 codepoints were made up for terminal usage, and the rest was too sparse for huge number of chars. IIRC it only had one set alpha chars too (uppercase), which is why Pascal is case insensitive nowadays.

Comment: Therefore escapes were in from the start afaik, and also appear in non Borland Pascals.

Answer (score 8):

These are called [digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_%28computing%29#Pascal)s. Has been described in [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements#Special_Symbols) too.

Comment: I remember C and C++ compilers supporting trigraphs, but it wasn't until Nick's article that I knew pascal had digraphs.